# using yii framework to send data filled in a form using ajax and save it in database

Tags: ajax, json, yii

Can anyone provide me a very simple example to send data using ajax (json format) in yii form and save it in the database.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639535/yii-framework-ajax-form

Comment: Or here - http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8219-solved-ajax-form-submission/